# PHP file_exists With Contents Instead of Name?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, file-exists

Is there a function built into PHP that acts like `file_exists`, but given file contents instead of the file name?

I need this because I have a site where people can upload an image. The image is stored in a file with a name determined by my program (`image_0.png image_1.png image_2.png image_3.png image_4.png ...`). I do not want my site to have multiple images with the same contents. This could happen if multiple people found a picture on the internet and all of them uploaded it to my site. I would like to check if there is already a file with the contents of the uploaded file to save on storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can compare exactly two files with PHP:

```
function compareFiles($file_a, $file_b)
{
    if (filesize($file_a) == filesize($file_b))
    {
        $fp_a = fopen($file_a, 'rb');
        $fp_b = fopen($file_b, 'rb');

        while (($b = fread($fp_a, 4096)) !== false)
        {
            $b_b = fread($fp_b, 4096);
            if ($b !== $b_b)
            {
                fclose($fp_a);
                fclose($fp_b);
                return false;
            }
        }

        fclose($fp_a);
        fclose($fp_b);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you keep the sha1 sum of each file you accept you can simply:

```
if ($known_sha1 == sha1_file($new_file))
```

Comment: Yes, but how could you see if a file with that contents already exists, without the name of file_b, would you just have to use the while loop in my answer to go through all of the files?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid. Comparing sha sums is the quicker method and you could include size reference in your filenames and check only similar sized ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to look look through the contents of all of your files. This is shown in the example below :

```
function content_exists($file){
  $image = file_get_contents($file);
  $counter = 0;
  while(file_exists('image_' . $counter . '.png')){
    $check = file_get_contents('image_' . $counter . '.png');
    if($image === $check){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      $counter ++;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The above function looks through all of your files and checks to see if the given image matches an image that is already stored. If the image already exists, `true` is returned and if the image does not exist `false` is returned. An example of how you can use this function shown is below :

```
if(content_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
  // upload
}
else{
  // do not upload
}
```

Comment: Expect quadratic behavior though.

Comment: Is there a faster way that you would reccomend?

Comment: Store hashes and compare those first. Make sure to verify false positives though.

Comment: So when an image is uploaded, hash the contents, then compare other stored hashes, then upload if the same hash does not already exist. Right?

Comment: I would gladly accept that as an answer if it were an answer with an example :), I know what you mean but I don't want to make an answer off of your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could store hashed files in a `.txt` file separated by a `\n` so that you could use the function below :

```
function content_exists($file){
  $file = hash('sha256', file_get_contents($file));
  $files = explode("\n", rtrim(file_get_contents('files.txt')));
  if(in_array($file, $files)){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

You could then use it to determine whether or not you should save the file as shown below :

```
if(content_exists($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
  // upload
}
else{
  // do not upload
}
```

Just make sure that when a file ***IS*** stored, you use the following line of code :

```
file_put_contents('files.txt', hash('sha256', file_get_contents($file)) . "\n");
```